# Adjustment of status/expired visa, wanting to travel within US by air

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, canadian-citizens

I am a Canadian citizen about to adjust status to permanent resident. Paperwork will be filed prior to my travel. I want to stay in the US for a vacation but my visa is expired and I am now considered without status.

Will this affect me in any way as far as travelling or my immigration process with USCIS?

Comment: when you talk about permanent residence, you mean in the US? I.e. you are a Canadian citizen and a permanent US resident and this permanence residence is about to expire - before you trip? If this is not the case, please add for your permanent residence and visa, which country is concerned.

Comment: "but my visa is expired and I am now considered without status" Visa expiration doesn't have anything to do with status. Visa is only for entry. You can enter on the day the visa expires but have status for however long you were given upon entry based on your classification. Also, Canadian citizens do not use a visa to enter the U.S. for most purposes.

Comment: Before migrating, I feel this question is unclear and requires more details.

Answer (score 3):

If you are not leaving the US, your expired visa will not pose a problem.  The expiration date of the visa is the last date on which you may show up at the US border and seek to be admitted to the country.  The expiration date has no effect on the allowed length of your stay.

I can't say for sure whether you will have problems on other grounds, however, because I do not know the implications of being "without status" or of having a pending application for permanent residency.

If it means that you should avoid coming to the attention of immigration enforcement officers, then you should consider whether your travel will increase the risk of that happening.  I would guess that the increase would only be significant if you plan to be travelling near enough to the Mexican border that you encounter internal immigration checkpoints.

If, on the other hand, your pending application for permanent residency means that you will have no fear of coming into contact with immigration enforcement officers, then you should have no reason to avoid traveling.